# Coded UI Tests not running properly when run together

Tags: c#, batch-file, coded-ui-tests

I have a bat files that executes the coded ui tests . The problem is these tests run properly when run separately one after another. i.e. comment the 30 odd test cases in the ordered test except one and run the batch file. It will pass that test case. But if I uncomment all these test cases and run it together one after another it fails. What might be the possible cause of this error. Please help. I have been going with this for almost one week and i have spent loads of hours.

Comment: How do you expect us to troubleshoot your script if you don't show us your script?

Comment: I just asked for the possible causes as I cannot share the code. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I'm flagging this to close as "too broad."

Comment: Please dont do that as other people are trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem once. Maybe your test dependent on another test, maybe your first test is deleting data and after that second test trying to get data that deleted, another solution is try to comment test one by one and run together you will cath test that causing problem
Hope helps!

Comment: Thanks alot.! Is there any possible way to refresh each UIMAp before a test case is run?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps tests are dependent on each other.  If they are reading/writing from/to files, that's definitely something to look out for.  Also, remember that the constructor is called once for the entire test class.  (Similarly, inline variable definitions are called once for the entire test class).  Of course [ClassInitialize] will also only be run once for all tests.  If all of that logic is moved into [TestInitialize], I would expect your problem to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys... Will surely try to work it out from here on. Getting an idea of whats happening....

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using a static class to hold an instance of the UI Map.

Here is the solution:

```
[TestInitialize]
      public void Init()
      {
         AppManager.ResetUIMap();
}
```

Then:

```
public static void ResetUIMap()
      {
         _map = new UIMap();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run coded UI test concurrently on the same machine, since they interact with the UI. [Run them on multiple machines to run in parallel](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2014/06/18/how-to-run-tests-on-different-machines-in-parallel/) or create some VMs etc.